# Programming a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a script that when I write a string to check if this string is a number or no if it isn't a number it should give me the input dialogue again, the is the code I tried:

```
<script>

var nombre;
nombre = parseInt(prompt("Donnez un nombre entre 0 et 999: "));
var nombreIsInt = false;

while(!nombreIsInt)
{
    if(isNaN(nombre))
        prompt("Svp Saisie un nombre entre 0 et 999: ");
    else
        nombreIsInt = true;
}

</script>
```

The problem is that when I write a number it gives me the input dialogue again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the prompt to nombre. Here:

```
<script>

var nombre;
nombre = parseInt(prompt("Donnez un nombre entre 0 et 999: "));
var nombreIsInt = false;

while(!nombreIsInt)
{
    if(isNaN(nombre))
        nombre = prompt("Svp Saisie un nombre entre 0 et 999: "); // the problem is here
    else
        nombreIsInt = true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: i would prefer Esailija's answer

Answer (score 5):

Try a do-while loop:

```
do {
    var nombre = parseInt(prompt("Donnez un nombre entre 0 et 999: "));
    var nombreIsInt = !isNaN(nombre);
} while (!nombreIsInt);
```